# NuGet Package Source limited to specific author

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore, nuget-server

Is it possible to configure a NuGet source to only allow pulling of packages from a specific root author ?

My specific use-case :

Visual Studio
NuGet Package Manager
Microsoft packages only

You might be wondering why ? The answer relates to trust in a corporate environment.

Comment: Have you tried rbennett485's suggestion? And is your issue solved?

Answer (score 0):

[Yes](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/lock-down-your-dependencies-using-configurable-trust-policies/#configure-trusted-package-authors)

e.g.

```
nuget.exe trusted-signers add -name Microsoft -certificateFingerprint 3F9001EA83C560D712C24CF213C3D312CB3BFF51EE89435D3430BD06B5D0EECE
```